# python library for identifying article topic

Tags: python, statistics, nlp, identifier, corpus

I have a large collection of articles, 80.000 and I want to extract those that are about one topic. Is there a python library or script in which i can input a manually chosen sample of articles about say Topic A then it would extract from the archive those articles about topic A by comparing the word used and their frequencies.

I have read about the Dunning method,  but is there a ready script that I can use preferably python.

Thanks

Comment: Are the articles in a machine-readable format? If so, you're probably better off using something like elastic search: http://www.elasticsearch.org/.

Comment: I have two archives, one is a set of txt files. The other one is NYTimes archives, I am using their API to access it.

Comment: The NYT API doesn't have any search features?

Comment: YEs, it does but what I am looking for is not a simple search, rather extract all the articles that talk about for instance arab spring. The keyword "arab spring" is not necessarily in present in all the articles.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything simple that "just works"--what you're describing is something like a full featured search engine. You can write one, I think, using nltk.scikits-learn, but I don't think there's an out-of-the-box free one for you to use. Aside from that, in order for the search engine to work, you'd have to index the NYT articles you plan to use. This means downloading the library from the NYT website, which I think they might take exception to.

Comment: Note: you may be able to BUY a search engine that works as you describe: http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/resources.html

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Natural Language Toolkit (http://nltk.org), which is an excellent Python library for working with and extracting meaning from natural language corpora like your article collection. Also, depending on what else you want to do, I recommend the scikit-learn library (http://scikit-learn.org/) for other machine learning tasks over the extracted text.

Answer (score 0):

Let me formalize my suggestions, if only for posterity.

0.) There's nothing that I know of which will do everything you want out of the box, that you can get for free. To pay for something, do a search for "google enterprise search".

1.) Index your documents with JSON using [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org). It's super-easy to set up. Elastic search has a lot of remedial search functions that won't solve your problem directly, but which will allow you to do simple key word searches while you experiment with building your own search engine.

2.) To search by subject, you'll have to write a learning routine. A very simple one, which is actually a pretty good place to start for your problem, is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py). That example will give you a starting point.